# Xorg very slow with intel graphics 2500, Lubuntu 18.04

Tags: graphics, intel, amd-graphics

I use Lubuntu 18.04 (with Gnome).

My pc has 2 graphics cards, one onboard intel 2500 (i5-3470), and one ATI Radeon HD7850.

At first, with wayland enabled, everything was smooth, with both my screens connected on the Intel card. The fact is that with wayland I could not change the resolution to my second screen to its native 1680x1050, so I disabled wayland to fix the issue by using good old xorg.

Now if I connect both my displays on the intel card, everything lags, mouse moves ok but every click or anything I type is VERY slow!
When I connect at least one of my displays on the ATI card everything runs smoothly. Also on the ATI card the resolution of my second screen gets detected without problems.

I do not want to use the ATI card, because I will dedicate it to a Windows VM to play games.

I see two possibilities here:
1) Fix the resolution of my second display on wayland (on intel card)
2) Fix the lagging problem with xorg (on intel card)

Is anything of the above doable?